# hide content when character are in textbox

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to hide some content of a page when characters are visible in a textbox and bring back the content when all characters in the textbox

HTML

```
 <ion-toolbar >
        <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search" (ionFocus)="callSearch($event)"></ion-searchbar >
      </ion-toolbar>
  <span *ngIf="showDefault">
<ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Suggested
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-start>
          <img src="">
        </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Fullname</h2>
      <p></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  </span>
```

JS

```
  showDefault: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public toastCtrl: ToastController,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController,
              public http: Http,
              public global: GlobalAPI) {

                this.showDefault = true;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

  callSearch($event){
    this.showDefault = false;
  }
```

Comment: you mean toggle?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz for this?

Comment: What i mean is when users starts typing in the textbox, the showDefault variable should be set to false, and user clears all thats in the textbox the showDefault should be set to true again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

HTML :

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search" (ionInput)="callSearch($event, searchInput)" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>
<span *ngIf="searchInput.length == 0">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Suggested
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Fullname</h2>
      <p></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</span>
```

TS :

```
showDefault: any;
searchInput: any = '';
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            public toastCtrl: ToastController,
            public alertCtrl: AlertController,
            public http: Http,
            public global: GlobalAPI) {

              this.showDefault = true;
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
}

callSearch($event, value){
  if(this.searchInput){
         this.showDefault = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: when the page loads the default content doesnt' show up

Comment: add `searchInput: any = '';` & `<span *ngIf="searchInput.length == 0">` I have updated answer

Comment: Great, Glad I could Help. :)